# nis authentication

Tags: nis

We have a working NIS setup installed on Linux SUSE 10.
We all aware that NIS is weak in terms of encrypting the user passwords. E.g. ypcat passwd command would show all the password details to a normal User.
How do we overcome this drawback without making big changes to our setup?
One workaround that comes to mind is changing permission of /usr/bin/ypcat and not allowing normal users to use this command at all. Huh ..I know thats not the best option to go for ... but still..!!!

Does NISPlus (NIS+) would help in this case?
If thats not possible then will LDAP a better option. But I tried  working out this solution on test system. It looks to me pretty complex. We use our existing NIS only for User Authentication purpose nothing more. Hence I am not sure if overhead of LDAP Setup will be worth.

Is there any other mechanism apart from NIS and LDAP?

Appreciate if any pointers in this case.

Comment: You can use SSSD (System Services Security Daemon) that provides security for LDAP, and is considered to be more secure than NIS.

Comment: you mean setup ldap and then with SSSD make it even more secure. But what I was looking for a simpler solution than LDAP and better than NIS.

Comment: `sssd` does not add any security to any backend service like ldap or NIS. Those backend services are only as secure as they are configured on the server side. If you really care about security, go the extra mile and configure a LDAP server with TLS/SSL and use `sssd` to query your ldap server aka directory service.